# How to detect if a window is "docked" on the desktop?

Tags: winapi

When a user presses, for example, `Windows-RightArrow` the window gets resized to the half of monitor's width and to its full height, and then gets "docked" to the right half of the monitor ([ref](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mthree/2015/08/26/now-available-windows-key-shortcuts-for-windows-10/)).

The question is if it's possible to detect either being in this state or being put into this state.

Obvioulsy, this can be *deduced* from `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` and the bunch, checking against monitor area and what not, but is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: "docked" is the wrong mental model, it is just a positioning aid provided by Explorer.  Nothing special happens to the window itself, it merely gets a convenient location and size.  So yes, you do have to check if they happen to match the monitor display area.  And keep in mind that the user might do this too by craftily using the mouse to move/size the window, albeit that the odds are not great on a large monitor.

Comment: @HansPassant Since you can undo the operation I'm guessing Windows does store state somewhere. Might not be accessible from usermode though.

Comment: Explorer would, not the window or OS.  No api for that.

Comment: @Anders - Exactly, hence the question.

Comment: Ran some tests and it appears that `rcNormalPosition` in `WINDOWPLACEMENT` saves the original (pre-docked) window position. So simply comparing it to the window's effective rectangle will show if the window is in a "special" state. Then, look at the `showCommand` - if it's `SW_SHOWNORMAL`, then we are in the docked state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy from my own comment above -

It appears that `rcNormalPosition` in `WINDOWPLACEMENT` saves the original (pre-docked) window position. So simply comparing it to the window's effective rectangle will show if the window is in a "special" state. Then, we just need to look at the `showCommand` - if it's `SW_SHOWNORMAL`, then we are in the docked state.

**Edit**

After field-testing this approach I have to amend the answer, because there exist cases on Windows 10 when the above conditions will be met for windows that are *not* vertically-docked.

An option that works is to **additionally** use `MonitorFromWindow`, followed by `GetMonitorInfo`, followed by comparing window's current `top` and `bottom` against those of `rcWork` from `MONITORINFO`.

So there was no miracle. No clean and easy way to do this.